# Atomic orbital, spin quantum number

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-spin

From wikipedia page about [Atomic orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital):

> Each such orbital can be occupied by a maximum of two electrons, each
> with its own spin quantum number s.

I though that all electrons had same spin quantum number s=1/2, being the difference the z-component of the angular momentum, $m_s \in \{ -1/2, 1/2 \}$.

I'm confusing the nomenclature ?

Comment: The two possible values of the spin quantum number (for electrons) is $-\frac12$ or $+\frac12$.

Comment: @Gert: do you means $s$ o $m_s$ ?

Comment: I mean $m_s$. The *spin quantum number*.

Comment: @Gert: thanks. Note extracted text from wiki page says "spin quantum number s", not $m_s$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it would be nice if physicists were consistent in their wording, but I don't think this will ever happen. Therefore, my advice is that you don't try to concentrate too much on the definitions like "the spin quantum number is $m_s$", but instead try to understand the concept. Furthermore, this should be simple for you, because I believe that you already got it right:

- Electrons are spin $1/2$ particles. This means that the magnitude of the spin is equal to $1/2$.
- If a particle possesses the spin $s$, there are $2s+1$ different quantisation configurations: $m_s = \{-s, -s+1, \ldots, +s\}$. These configurations  can visualise  by assuming that the spin of the particle is only allowed to "point" in certain directions in space (w.r.t. the arbitrarily chosen quantisation axis).  So, if $s=1/2$, we get $2\cdot 1/2 + 1 = 2$ configurations, $m_s= \pm 1/2$. If instead the spin is $s=3/2$, we get $2\cdot 3/2 + 1 = 4$ different configurations, $m_s= \{-3/2, -1/2, +1/2, +3/2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum numbers may be intrinsic describing particles, like lepton number, spin, charge etc, or they arise because of the solution of thee quantum mechanical differential equation modeling the system:

> [In the solution](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/qunoh.html#c2) to the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom, three quantum numbers arise from the space geometry of the solution and a fourth arises from electron spin. No two electrons can have an identical set of quantum numbers according to the Pauli exclusion principle

[image: atomleve]

R(r)   Principal quantum number     [image: q1]

P(θ)    Orbital quantum number       [image: q2]

F(φ)    Magnetic quantum number    [[image: q3]][5

Spin quantum number    [image: q6]

In the case of the Pauli exclusion principle it is the projected two values of electron spins that allows them to occupy the same l,m,n orbital. The application of a magnetic field would also end up differentiating the orbitals.

Comment: Some bug in my edit, I am trying to connect it. look at the link

Comment: Thanks. Link says "spin quantum number $m_s$", but the wiki page says "spin quantum number s". Contradiction ?

Comment: the wiki meaning is the spin for a particle, that characterises it as a fermion or a boson, look at the table of particles  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle . The projection of spin is also a quantum number and characterizes the orbital

Comment: If wiki means spin of particle, it is 1/2 for both electrons, phrase "two electrons, each with its own spin quantum number s" is incorrect. Wiki should say "two electrons, each with its own projection of spin $m_s$" ?

Comment: actually yes, both electrons have spin 1/2 but spin projection in the orbital different